# How do I insert a specific element/text at a specific location in an XML file using python?

Tags: python, xml, xml.etree

I'm currently using `xml.etree.cElementTree` in Python to parse XML files. I would like to know if it's possible to read data from another file and insert it at a specific location in an XML file.

Here's the XML file I'm working with:

```
<Data>
   <Action>A</Action>
   <FinalDate>2018-08-24</FinalDate>
   <InitialDate>2011-08-19</InitialDate>
   <DateOperation>
       <DateOperationCode>Append</DateOperationCode>
       <Date>2017-08-21</Date>
   </DateOperation>
<Data>
```

In this file, I would like to insert dates that are read from another file as text after the line "**2017-08-21**", so that the updated XML file can look like this:

```
<Data>
   <Action>A</Action>
   <FinalDate>2018-08-24</FinalDate>
   <InitialDate>2011-08-19</InitialDate>
   <DateOperation>
       <DateOperationCode>Append</DateOperationCode>
       <Date>2017-08-21</Date>
       <Date>2017-09-21</Date> #new date
       <Date>2017-10-21</Date> #new date
       <Date>2017-11-21</Date> #new date
   </DateOperation>
<Data>
```

I tried different ways to insert the dates, but none have worked so far.

Comment: Try looking at [Insert a Node for an element in XML with Python/ElementTree](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4788633/insert-a-node-for-an-element-in-xml-with-python-elementtree?adlt=strict&toWww=1&redig=2554219974E943C6B6BD0A48BFDACC9E).

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend, in this case, using lxml instead of ElementTree, because of the former's better xpath support.

Also, both your xml files are not well formed, for various reasons.

So, assuming I understand you correctly, I would do the following:

```
from lxml import etree

#the xml in both files is fixed, as I best understand it
file1 = """<Data>
   <Action>A</Action>
   <FinalDate>2018-08-24</FinalDate>
   <InitialDate>2011-08-19</InitialDate>
   <DateOperation>
       <DateOperationCode>Append</DateOperationCode>
       <Date>2017-08-21</Date>
    </DateOperation>
</Data>
"""
file2 ="""<Data>
   <Action>A</Action>
   <FinalDate>2018-08-24</FinalDate>
   <InitialDate>2011-08-19</InitialDate>
   <DateOperation>
       <DateOperationCode>Append</DateOperationCode>
       <Date>2017-08-21</Date>
       <Date>2017-09-21</Date>
       <Date>2017-10-21</Date> 
       <Date>2017-11-21</Date>
        </DateOperation>
</Data>"""

doc1 = etree.XML(file1)
doc2 = etree.XML(file2)
baseline= doc1.xpath('//DateOperation/Date/text()')[0]

dest = doc1.xpath('//DateOperation')[0]
for d in doc2.xpath(f'//Date[.="{baseline}"]//following-sibling::Date'):
    dest.append(d)
print(etree.tostring(doc1).decode())
```

Output:

```
<Data>
   <Action>A</Action>
   <FinalDate>2018-08-24</FinalDate>
   <InitialDate>2011-08-19</InitialDate>
   <DateOperation>
       <DateOperationCode>Append</DateOperationCode>
       <Date>2017-08-21</Date>
    <Date>2017-09-21</Date>
       <Date>2017-10-21</Date> 
       <Date>2017-11-21</Date>
        </DateOperation>
</Data>
```

I notice that file1, after the modifications, looks very much like file2. If that's the case in real life, why not just use file2?

Comment: Second file was use more as an example of what I want to get. To be clear, I want to pull dates from another file (preferably a xlsx file) and insert them in file 1 after the line "<DateOperationCode>Append</DateOperationCode>"  as you did in your solution. Also, you are right, the file formed properly since it's just an extract from a bigger XML file.

Comment: @NARUTOUZUNAKI "I want to pull dates from another file (preferably a xlsx file)" - so have you successfully done it or is your actuall question about how to do it?

Comment: No, I'm having difficulty with this.

Comment: @NARUTOUZUNAKI Then I would suggest posting it as a separate question, explaining what the problem is and what you expect to end up with. Once you have that, we can go back to this question, if it's still relevant.

Answer (score 0):

The below works

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
import pandas as pd

xml = '''<Data>
   <Action>A</Action>
   <FinalDate>2018-08-24</FinalDate>
   <InitialDate>2011-08-19</InitialDate>
   <DateOperation>
       <DateOperationCode>Append</DateOperationCode>
       <Date>2017-08-21</Date>
  </DateOperation>
</Data>
'''

root = ET.fromstring(xml)
dates_to_add = ['2022-09-21', '2017-03-11', '2017-05-25']
date_oper_root = root.find('.//DateOperation')
for date in dates_to_add:
    new_date = ET.Element("Date")
    new_date.text = date
    date_oper_root.append(new_date)
ET.dump(root)
```

Comment: Thank you for your solution. However, the output put all the dates on one line instead on a different line one after the other: "Date>2022-09-21</Date><Date>2017-03-11</Date><Date>2017-05-25</Date></DateOperation>". I want the new dates to be display exactly as in the second XML file. Do you know if there's a way to do that?

Comment: For xml new lines are not important? Why it's important for you?